# Should I inform the user a slider actually has a margin?

Tags: gui-design, labels, sliders

I have a configuration dialog that contains a percentage slider:

[image]

The user can set a range of 10% to 90% on this slider (don't ask why). In reality, the user is actually configuring a range with a 5% margin. So if the user sets the slider on 25%, in the background, the range is set to 20%-30%. The margin cannot be defined by the user.

I was wondering if I should inform the user that a margin is used instead of the specific percentage the user is configuring, and if yes how I should do this.

I was thinking of simply changing the percentage label behind the slider to 35% - 45% or highlighting a small area left and right of the slider handle like so:

[image]

or a combination of both.

Comment: Will the margin ever be revealed to the user? For example, if they choose 25%, will it show somewhere in the settings that they chose 20%-30%, because that discrepancy may cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing the label to show the whole range instead of just the centerpoint is a must.

Merely changing the area behind the selector handle is likely to be misinterpreted as being a larger handle. Because with scrolling interfaces, you often get scaling issues.

But while just highlighting the background isn't enough, it can be modified to make it more usable. I mentioned it being confused for a larger handle... how about just making it the handle? It'll make it a larger touch target as well as show the whole range, while being less visually cluttered than having both handle and highlight:

[image]